# Getting frame from video

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#pragma comment (lib , "opencv_core244d.lib")
#pragma comment (lib ,"opencv_highgui244d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib , "opencv_imgproc244d.lib")
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromFile("try.avi");

    IplImage* frame = NULL;
    do
    {
        frame = skipNFrames(capture, 1);
        cvNamedWindow("frame", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvShowImage("frame", frame);
        cvWaitKey(0);
    } while( frame != NULL );

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("frame");
    cvReleaseImage(&frame);

    return 0;
}
```

This is my program to get frames from the video , but when i run this program , it works , it show me the video , but its not saving the frames automatically (without using any button or mouse) , which should save in my directory

Comment: Additional remark: since you are using a recent OpenCV (2.4.4) and a C++ API via opencv.hpp, you should take full advantage of this API by using C++ classes instead of C structs, i.e. cv::Mat instead of IplImage*, cv::namedWindow(), etc. You will gain a lot of practical benefits such as auto memory management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<cv.h>
#include<highgui.h>
#include<cxcore.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

int c=1;
IplImage* img=0;
char buffer[1000];
CvCapture* cv_cap = cvCaptureFromFile("try.avi");
cvNamedWindow("Video",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
while(1) {

img=cvQueryFrame(cv_cap);
cvShowImage("Video",img);
sprintf(buffer,"D:/image%u.jpg",c);
cvSaveImage(buffer,img);
c++;
  if (cvWaitKey(100)== 27) break;
}

cvDestroyWindow("Video"); 
return 0;
}
```

Try this , this will work

Answer (score 4):

To see each frame of the video individually use `cvWaitKey(0)`. It shows current frame of the video and wait for a key press infinitely. So to see the next frame press a key.

Comment: but how to save those frames and i want from program to save those frames automatically

Comment: It is so easy. just save individual frames with different name.

Answer (score 3):

To save each frame individually,

1. `#include<stdio.h>`
2. Declare a global variable

   `int flag=0;`
3. add following code just below to **cvWaitKey(0)** :

   ```
   char *str=new char[50];

   flag++;
   sprintf(str,"%d",flag);
   strcat(str," frame");
   strcat(str,".jpg");
   Mat image=frame;
   imwrite(str,image);
   ```

Comment: +1 for answer , Which library is use for Mat and imwrite ? because it show it undefined

Comment: These functions are in namespace cv::. So you can use them with `cv::Mat` and `cv::imwrite`. Or define a namespace with `using namespace cv`.

Comment: @baban program should save the frames automatically , I don't want to save the pic through pressing any button or any external use

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`cvSaveImage()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite) to explicitly save each frame.
This should be done in your loop, wherever you want to save the frame.
Obviously, if you want to save each frame with a different name you have to generate different names for each call. @baban shows one way to do it.